# What is the query to add a field in schema and create index on that field in mongodb after schema creation?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design, schema

I wanted to know a way to add a field in collection and create an index on that field after schema creation. Problem is that i dont know field name while creating schema it will be coming from an end point later on and after that i will have name of that field.

I have tried using Model.createIndexes({unknown_field_name:1}); but index is not showing up in mongoDB compass.

I tried using Model.schema.index({unknown_field_name:1}) this is also not showing index in mongoDB compass.